# filter incoming emails in outlook

Tags: outlook, ms-office

I would like to automatically put incoming emails which are not from certain domains go to a specific folder in outlook. For example I want any emails that are not from xyz.com and personname@gmail.com to go into a folder `outside emails` .

I found [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1991-outlook-move-email-from-domain-to-folder.html) link but it is not useful as i dont know the exact domains from where I would get those emails

I have Microsoft office 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating filtering rules, MS Office doesn't provide filtering for NOT conditions. However, this can be achieved by adding exception to the rule. You'll be able to find it after you set the conditions and the actions.

I would suggest to process all messages with an exception of *Sender address includes* as the domain you want to whitelist (xyz.com). Similarly, you can add more exceptions to this rule.

You can refer to [this article](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/not-conditions-for-rules).